# Playing a sound in sync with an animation

Tags: android, animation, audio

I have an enlarge animation (enlarges a text view) that repeats 4 times (or repeats 3 times, enlarges 4 times in total).

I'm trying to play a sound (like a piano note) in sync with each enlargement of the text view.

I originally recorded the sound file so that it plays 4 times, and I tried to adjust the animation duration to try sync it, but it goes out of sync after a couple of animation repeats.

I have an animation listener and I'm playing the sound with media player in the on animation start method.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: you have methods in the animation listener which will tell you when the animation starts/ends/restarts. Play your sound in those methods

Comment: Yes I know, and that's what I'm doing. The question is how to sync the sound with each repeat/enlargement of the animation. I'll play around with on animation repeat

Comment: you don't need to sync it somehow, you only need to play the sound in the required listener method.

Comment: OK, another question. How do I make my Mediaplayer object I create in "on animation start" accessible/usable in "on animation end" and "on animation repeat"? Thanks

Comment: create it before, make it global.

Comment: OK, done. In "on animation repeat" I have this: if(mplayer.isplaying()) {mplayer.stop}; mplayer.start();. But the sound only plays once.

Comment: I have logged a message to the logs in onAnimationStart(works, start message gets logged), onAnimationEnd (works, end message gets logged), and onAnimationRepeat (doesn't work, repeat message doesn't get logged). So it seems the onAnimationRepeat never fires even though my repeatcount is positive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, So in reading past problems of settings in XML animations not working, or being ignored, such as  repeatCount (although I haven't had those issues, I guess those bugs must have been fixed), I decided to try not use XML at all, and rather create my animation in java only, like so:

```
ScaleAnimation animation=new ScaleAnimation(1.0f,3.0f,1.0f,3.0f,50f,50f);
animation.setDuration(900);
animation.setRepeatCount(7);
animation.setRepeatMode(animation.REVERSE);
view.startAnimation(animation);
```

Now in the AnimationListener, all the onAnimationStart, onAnimationEnd, and onAnimationRepeat all fire perfectly and reliably, and everything works. I guess java doesn't play nice with XML based animations.

Comment: I've marked my own post as the answer because it solved my problem